# Tikz-Dependency: Space between arc and the label

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{dependency}[arc edge, arc angle=80, text only label, label style={above}]
        \begin{deptext}[column sep=.7cm]
        My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \\
        PRP \& NN \& RB \& VBZ \& VBG \\
        \end{deptext}
        \depedge{2}{1}{poss}
    \end{dependency}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What key controls the space between the arc and the label above it? (In the example above, the text `poss`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `positioning` library, and give `above=10pt` (or at least, the distance you want) in your style definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{dependency}[arc edge, arc angle=80, text only label, label style={above=10pt}]
        \begin{deptext}[column sep=.7cm]
        My \& dog \& also \& likes \& eating \\
        PRP \& NN \& RB \& VBZ \& VBG \\
        \end{deptext}
        \depedge{2}{1}{poss}
    \end{dependency}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: dependency]

Comment: You don't actually need the `positioning` library for `above=<distance>`.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about giving `above left=5pt and 7pt` for example ;)